# Can anyone help with this matrix problem?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-rank

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnxjp.png)

In this image, there's a question about asking to get the determinant of matrix D. I'm stuck on how to represent it as using only a and n.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched, and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Hint:  Your matrix can be written as $\text{Ones}_{n\times n} + (a-1)I_{n\times n}$.  What can you say about the eigenvalues and the dimensions of their corresponding eigenspaces?  Can you relate the trace to this and all of that to the determinant?

Comment: Yes thank you for your kind help!!!